# Show the number of likes from multiple pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to get the number of likes on multiple facebook pages and display it on a webpage.

For example if I had four different pages on my site for each of the teams in a school competition.

On the red teams page I only want the user to be able to like the red page but I want to show how many likes the other teams have.

I have reviewed the documentation but don't seem to be able to find a way to do this.  Is anyone able to point me in the right direction here?

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Number of Votes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Red Team</td>
        <td>
            <span>100 <!--Display number of likes from http://www.facebook.com/redteam --></span>
            <span class="btn-fblike">
                <fb:like href="http%3a%2f%2fwww.facebook.com%2fredteampage" layout="standard" colorscheme="dark" width="320" height="25"/>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Blue Team</td>
        <td>
            <span>80<!--Display number of likes from http://www.facebook.com/blueteam --></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Green Team</td>
        <td>
            <span>60 <!--Display number of likes from http://www.facebook.com/greenteam --></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some further investigation found that the best way to do this is use [Facebook Query Language](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)